# .htaccess causing 500 Error while modifying it to add Authorization Header (PHP Service Api)

Tags: php, apache, rest

I added the undermentioned script to my .htaccess file to enable adding of Authorization Header but causes 500 error on request to my php apis. Can anyone help me out? thank you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization}  ^(.*)$ 
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Comment: What message is in the apache error log file?

Comment: checked out the errors but none is related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't from the .htaccess file, i noticed the interval server error occured due to fetchall in mysqli which i didn't configured properly in my server. so, what i did is to enable nd_mysqli and all was fine and sound. thank you.